# Selecting specific time based data in mySql

Tags: mysql

im having a issue with my syntax.

SELECT msg_text FROM planes.acars BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31';

i am trying to get all the msg_text between jan 1 and jan 31

Comment: You need to use `BETWEEN` with a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the full structure of the tables, I think you need to add a WHERE clause that specifies the date of the msg_text

```
SELECT msg_text FROM planes.acars
WHERE msg_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
```

If we can see the tables, this might help in specifying the answer

Comment: i got it, the date column is called date_dd_mm_yyyy in table so syntax was mysql> select msg_text from planes.acars where date_dd_mm_yyyy between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31';